# <select> get selected option number

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a `<select>` with option, but what i want when i select a option to get the option number.

I do not want him to grab attributes(No value & text). Because it is dynamic.

**Example:**

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

When i select Apple, that I get a response 1. so with Pear: 2. and so on.

**I have found:** [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_length), But this will show how many option are available.

What someone here a solution for?

Comment: Why don't you assign a value to each option? Which is the reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: The `selectedIndex` property contains the option number.

Comment: `$('option:selected').index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this using plain JavaScript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var selectEle = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    selectEle.addEventListener('change', function(item){
        console.log(selectEle.selectedIndex + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>`.

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  console.log("Selected option is " + this.selectedIndex);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Choose a fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This one is perfect, because it start with 0. thanks you.

Comment: @jurdekker didn't you ask in your question to start with 1?

Comment: Yes, but sorry. i forgot it.

Comment: This starts with 1 because `0` is the option that means they didn't select anything. But if you get rid of that you can easily just add 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    $(#mySelect option).each(function(index){
        if ($(this).attr('selected') {
            console.log(index);
        }
    });
})
```

You may have to change out .attr() for .prop() depending on your version of Query

May also use

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    $("#mySelect option").index($("#mySelect option:selected"))
})
```

Comment: Why not use `$("#mySelect option:selected")` instead of a loop?

Comment: instead of `.each` you can directly use  `$('option:selected' , this).index()`